# How can I add one title on a scoreboard with two teams?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image: porvmel]

I am still working on the mini game where you kill the other team's leader, then you win. The problem is with the scoreboard. I added two teams, red and blue. The objective is `stat.killEntity.Ozelot`, so when you kill an ocelot, you get a point, then you win. The problem is when I add them, the title (white letters) always says blue.  Can I set it to says stat? But then I can't add both teams; I can't have two stats.

Comment: Please stop adding your username, and please help to all your questions.  We already know who you are, and you wouldn't be asking if you didn't need help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have 2 separate teams on the scoreboard, create an objective for your scores, I'll use "score" in this example with the command `/scoreboard objectives add score dummy Score`. Then to test it, do `/scoreboard players set Blue score 1`, and set the display to `sidebar`. Then, keep your old objective, and have a clock with command blocks testing for `/testfor @a[score_ocelotKill_min=1,team=red]` and one for blue, with comparator output to a command block with /scoreboard players add Red score 1` or Blue. It's a bit confusing, but it works.

EDIT:
Use 2 command blocks with `score_ocelotKill_min=1` and `score_wolfKill_min=1` to have an ocelot or wolf. Don't forget to actually setup the scoreboard objectives with `/scoreboard objectives add ocelotKill stat.killEntity.Ozelot` or `/scoreboard objectives add wolfKill stat.killEntity.Wolf`

Comment: its not working but i did delete all my objectives so what am i suppose to have and you can also select wolves so i have to put two sets right

Comment: Added edits. Hope it works. If you need to, add a display name as an extra parameter after stat.killEntity.entityName.

Comment: im kind of getting lost

Comment: where you put ocelotkill i want to put leader stat but i cant add two words when i use an underscore it shows the underscore in the sidebar

Comment: Use `/scoreboard objectives add leaderstat stat.killEntity.Ozelot Leader Stat`